# create in python a specific F-curve

Tags: python, animation, scripting, fcurves

Recent versions of Blender do not generate any type of F-curve.

In particular, after inserting a key position image on the object, I would like to enter:

```
-for Xposition: f (t) = 8 * cos (t ^ 3)

-for Yposition: f (t) = 8 * sin (t ^ 3)

-for Zposition: f (t) = 0
```

which is impossible with an F-curve modifier, to create on the object a circular plane motion of radius 8 and accelerated

All that remains is Python.

1) A python script for this?

2) **More generally**, I'm looking for a tutorial elaborating a Python script to enter **any type of mathematical function** of a single variable, representing an F-curve related to any keyframe insertion.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "Recent versions of Blender do not generate any type of F-curve."?

Comment: for example,it's no possible to create a F-curve like this:
Y(X)=exp(X)+(1-X)²/(1+X)
Y(X)=arcsin(X)
Y(x)=cos(X^3)

Answer (score 2):

**The Driver System**

Can use the driver system for this.  An fcurve is a series of `frame, value` points. The value of an fcurve at any frame can be found via `FCurve.evaluate(frame)` A scripted expression driver evaluates its expression at each frame.  `context.scene.current_frame` is already known to the driver namespace as `frame`, as are a considerable number of math methods and properties including `sin`, `cos` and `pi`

Type simple expressions directly into the property preceded by a hash "#".

[image]

Will show as purple if all is Ok.  Can edit at any time by clicking on the driver.
[image]

Comment: Just tested it. Cool, but frame really needs to be divided or you have jumpy cow disease. Since it's accelerating rapidly, better make it a high number if the scene is supposed to be longer than 2 seconds.

Comment: @Haunt_House Yes, for seconds divide frame by `fps`. or `100` or whatever . There is a `bpy.utils.time_from_fame(frame)` (or similar OTOMH) Thought that the frame was the typical blender unit of time for keyframes in an fcurve.  Anyway the +/- nature of trig functions and a cubic can be expected to oscillate  for all but low values of time.

Comment: The scene might be in slow motion ( :